# Async doesn't work for long vectors

Tags: performance, c++11, asynchronous, optimization

I am doing some parallel programming with `async`. I have an integrator and in a test program I wanted to see whether if dividing a vector in 4 subvectors actually takes one fourth of the time to complete the task. 
I had an initial issue about the time measured, now solved as `steady_clock()` measures **real** and not CPU time.

I tried the code with different vector lenghts. For short lenghts (<10e5 elements) the direct integration is faster: normal, as the .get() calls and the sum take their time.

For intermediate lenghts (about 1e8 elements) the integration followed the expected time, giving 1 s as the first time and 0.26 s for the second time.

For long vectors(10e9 or higher) the second integration takes much more time than the first, more than 3 s against a similar or greater time.

Why? What is the process that makes the divide and conquer routine slower?

A couple of additional notes: Please note that I pass the vectors by reference, so that cannot be the issue, and keep in mind that this is a test code, thus the subvector creation is not the point of the question.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<thread>
#include<future>
#include<ctime>
#include<chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

typedef steady_clock::time_point tt;

double integral(const std::vector<double>& v, double dx) //simpson 1/3
{
  int n=v.size();
  double in=0.;
  if(n%2 == 1) {in+=v[n-1]*v[n-1]; n--;}
  in=(v[0]*v[0])+(v[n-1]*v[n-1]);

  for(int i=1; i<n/2; i++)
      in+= 2.*v[2*i] + 4.*v[2*i+1];

  return in*dx/3.;
}

int main()
{
double h=0.001;
vector<double> v1(100000,h); // a vector, content is not important
// subvectors
vector<double> sv1(v1.begin(), v1.begin() + v1.size()/4), 
           sv2(v1.begin() + v1.size()/4 +1,v1.begin()+ 2*v1.size()/4),
           sv3( v1.begin() + 2*v1.size()/4+1, v1.begin() + 3*v1.size()/4+1), 
           sv4( v1.begin() + 3*v1.size()/4+1, v1.end());

double a,b;
cout << "f1" << endl;
tt bt1 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
// complete integration: should take time t
a=integral(v1, h);

tt et1 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
duration<double> time_span = duration_cast<duration<double>>(et1 - bt1);
cout << time_span.count() << endl;




future<double> f1, f2,f3,f4;
cout << "f2" << endl;
tt bt2 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
// four integrations: should take time t/4
f1 = async(launch::async, integral, ref(sv1), h);
f2 = async(launch::async, integral, ref(sv2), h);
f3 = async(launch::async, integral, ref(sv3), h);
f4 = async(launch::async, integral, ref(sv4), h);
b=f1.get()+f2.get()+f3.get()+f4.get();

tt et2 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
duration<double> time_span2 = duration_cast<duration<double>>(et2 - bt2);
cout << time_span2.count() << endl;

cout << a << "  " << b << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It depends on how many cores you have.  If you only have 2 then each core has to jump between two threads and the cache locality is messed up.  You should only ever start as many threads as you have cores.

Comment: Your code [doesn't seem to compile](https://ideone.com/1WE14L).

Comment: Use a thread pool. Or openmp.

Comment: Jerry: I got 8 cores. The fact that it works for intermediate vector lenghts shows that they are enought (>4)

Comment: Fred: fixed. It was a copy of some parts.

Comment: rustyx: Thanks. Could you explain yourself with an example?